# Exemple d'emploi de « plateformisation » pour désigner un effet perturbateur de cette pratique sur un secteur d'activité ?

Tags: vocabulaire, terminologie, informatique, économie

En [lisant](https://www.lapresse.ca/affaires/entreprises/201905/03/01-5224487-australie-vaste-recours-collectif-contre-uber.php) qu'une société prédatrice va faire l'objet d'un vaste recours collectif je jette un coup d’œil à la définition de [*plateformisation*](http://granddictionnaire.com/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=26543589) (« Fait d'adopter un modèle d'entreprise dans lequel une organisation, au moyen d'une plateforme Web, agit à titre d'intermédiaire entre particuliers [...] », GDT) et on y indique que par extension « le terme *plateformisation* est parfois employé pour désigner l'effet perturbateur qu'une telle pratique peut entraîner sur un secteur d'activité » (GDT).

Peut-on dénicher et produire un exemple d'un tel emploi de *plateformisation* ?

Answer (score 1):

Oui, on peut, et ce chercheur en a meme fait un sujet de recherche: [article](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S1775878518304776) et [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ssYRjBcSZU8).

Comment: Dans le résumé du travail en question, on trouve des phrases comme « impacts de la plateformisation en santé et sécurité au travail » ou « plateformisation, ce nouveau concept prend de plus en plus de place dans l’économie, impactant jusqu’à la disruption à la fois... » mais la _plateformisation_ n'y « désigne » pas l'_effet_ ou l'_impact_ sinon pourquoi aurait-on besoin d'employer ces deux termes. Ou est-ce que je comprends mal le sens de « désigner » ? Désigner est-ce évoquer, introduire ou _nommer_. Ai-je raison de chercher une phrase où le terme se substitue à _effet perturbateur_ ?

Comment: Selon moi, il faut interpréter la phrase comme ceci : *Le terme plateformisation est parfois employé pour désigner la pratique de plateformisation + son effet perturbateur sur le secteur d'activité.*. en gros, le terme englobe parfois la pratique en elle-même et la critique sous-jacente de cette pratique.

Comment: Je pense que @Sharcoux a raison, et je rajouterais que l'idée derrière cette désignation correspond à la connotation négative du terme dans la société actuelle. L'auteur de la définition a possiblement voulu accentuer cet aspect.